# How to access Geometry Child Node GLTFSceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, gltf

I have loaded GLTF MODEL in AR Swift iOS app. But do not find the geometry value. How can I get geometry value of node? I have required Change custom materials of every node

```
import GLTFSceneKit

var scene: SCNScene
do {
  let sceneSource = try GLTFSceneSource(named: "art.scnassets/Box/glTF/Box.gltf")
  scene = try sceneSource.scene()
} catch {
  print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
  return
}
```